# Remove duplicate item from array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm looking for an easy way of removing a duplicate value from an array.  I figured out how to detect if there is a duplicate or not, just I don't know how to "push" it from the value.  For example, if you go to the link provided, and then type, "abca" ***(press return/enter key after each letter)***.. it will alert "duplicate!"

But I also want to figure out how to remove that duplicate from the textarea?

http://jsfiddle.net/P3gpp/

This is the part that seems to not be working ::

```
sort = sort.push(i);
textVal = sort;
return textVal;
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Why do it the hard way, it can be done more easily using javascript filter function which is specifically for this kind of operations:

```
var arr = ["apple", "bannana", "orange", "apple", "orange"];

arr = arr.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
           return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
    });


---------------------
Output: ["apple", "bannana", "orange"]
```

Comment: I think that, in 2014, five years into the EcmaScript 5 era and with IE8 below 10% of world browser share, we can safely call this the correct answer. If one is concerned with support for old versions of IE, a polyfill library for EC5 can be used.

Comment: (I would note though that while 'filter' is the right answer 90% of the time, it isn't appropriate on its own in circumstances where there may be references to the original array elsewhere because it creates a new array and the original array object is left intact.)

Answer (score 6):

Based on user2668376 solution, this will return a new array without duplicates.

```
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates = function () {
    return this.filter(function (item, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(item) == index;
    });
};
```

After that you can do:

```
[1, 3, 3, 7].removeDuplicates();
```

Result will be; `[1, 3, 7]`.

Comment: So, if user2668376 already has answered with this solution, why repeat it? Btw, you have a `self` too much.

Comment: His solution is without .prototype. In my opinion it is much better to use that. I deleted the var self = this;

Answer (score 4):

These are the functions I created/use for removing duplicates:

```
var removeDuplicatesInPlace = function (arr) {
    var i, j, cur, found;
    for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cur = arr[i];
        found = false;
        for (j = i - 1; !found && j >= 0; j--) {
            if (cur === arr[j]) {
                if (i !== j) {
                    arr.splice(i, 1);
                }
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
};

var removeDuplicatesGetCopy = function (arr) {
    var ret, len, i, j, cur, found;
    ret = [];
    len = arr.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cur = arr[i];
        found = false;
        for (j = 0; !found && (j < len); j++) {
            if (cur === arr[j]) {
                if (i === j) {
                    ret.push(cur);
                }
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

So using the first one, this is how your code could look:

```
function cleanUp() {
    var text = document.getElementById("fld"),
        textVal = text.value,
        array;

    textVal = textVal.replace(/\r/g, " ");
    array = textVal.split(/\n/g);

    text.value = removeDuplicatesInPlace(array).join("\n");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VrcN6/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to remove the duplicates. You need a helper object to keep track of how many times an item has been seen.

```
function cleanUp() 
{
    var textBox = document.getElementById("fld"),
    array = textBox.value.split(/\r?\n/g),
    o = {},
    output;

    output = array.reduce(function(prev, current) {
        var key = '$' + current;

        // have we seen this value before?
        if (o[key] === void 0) {
            prev.push(current);
            o[key] = true;
        }

        return prev;
    }, []);

    // write back the result
    textBox.value = output.join("\n");
}
```

The output of the `reduce()` step can be used directly to populate the text area again, without affecting the original sort order.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P3gpp/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with just an object:

```
function removeDuplicates(text) {
    var seen = {};
    var result = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var char = text.charAt(i);

        if (char in seen) {
            continue;
        } else {
            seen[char] = true;
            result += char;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function cleanUp() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("fld");

    elem.value = removeDuplicates(elem.value);
}
```

Comment: Consider: `result += char in seen? '' : seen[char] = char;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5];
unique = [];

function findUnique(val)
{
  status = '0';  
  unique.forEach(function(itm){
    if(itm==val){ 
      status=1;
    }
  })
  return status;
}

arr3.forEach(function(itm){
  rtn =  findUnique(itm);
  if(rtn==0)
    unique.push(itm);
});

console.log(unique);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```