# Javascript: How to remove only one value from duplicate array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array `['2530491','2530491','2530491','2530492']` the `2530491` is duplicated thrice, and I want to remove a single value of 2530491 from 3 of them, so the output would be like : 
`['2530491','2530491','2530492']`.

```
fileArrayAnnounce_size = jQuery.grep(fileArrayAnnounce_size, function(value){
  return value != file_size.metas[0].size;
});
```

I try grip but it removes all value which same. I want to remove only a single value from duplicates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008025/remove-duplicate-item-from-array-javascript

Comment: what are the rules exactly....allow 2 duplicates but no more?

Comment: @charlietfl that seems to be the case. Twice but not thrice.

Comment: Even more than 2 duplicates as long as I removed a single of it. Just to remove single value from duplicate regardless how many duplicates

Comment: So if there are four of the same, you still only wan't to remove one item? May you clarify the rules?

Comment: @evolutionxbox but no it's not clear and needs to be stated as there are different ways to interpret still

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes

Comment: @charlietfl Indeed, I've asked for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if given element has dupe elements or not, if so - remove just  one duplicate entry of specified element from the original array.

```js
var arr = ['2530491','2530491','2530491','2530492'],
    hash = [...new Set(arr)];
    hash.forEach((v,i) => arr.indexOf(v) != arr.lastIndexOf(v) ? arr.splice(arr.indexOf(v), 1) : null);
    
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I like the simplicity

Answer (score 5):

You can use `splice` and `indexOf` to remove the first instance:

```
fileArrayAnnounce_size.splice(fileArrayAnnounce_size.indexOf('2530491'), 1)
```

A safer way:

```
var index = fileArrayAnnounce_size.indexOf('2530491')
if (index > -1) {
    fileArrayAnnounce_size.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Check and remove duplicates:

```
var mapOfValues = fileArrayAnnounce_size.reduce(function(vals, current) {
    if (vals[current]) {
        vals[current]++;
    } else {
        vals[current] = 1;
    }

    return vals;
}, {});
```

And now check and remove anything with more than 1 value:

```
for (var value in mapOfValues) {
    if (mapOfValues[value] > 1) {
        var idx = fileArrayAnnounce_size.indexOf(value);
        fileArrayAnnounce_size.splice(idx, 1);
    }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1277mxt9/

Comment: Don't you also need a check as to whether a value has a duplicate? Otherwise all values would be removed.

Comment: don't see how this verifies a duplicate exists

Comment: I mean, this works _but_ only if you know the duplicate values.

Comment: Updated the code to find duplicates or more, and then a way to remove 1 of each of those values

Comment: OP has changed the requirements again... remove one, and only one, duplicate item from a set of duplicate items, no matter how many. 3 dupes become 2, 4 dupes become 3, etc.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's all that the edit does ...remove one instance

Comment: Pretty sure the edit above works fine @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` and pass one object as `thisArg` parameter to use it as hash table.

```js
var data = ['2530491','2530491','2530491','2530492', '2530492'];

var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  if(!this[e]) this[e] = 1
  else if (this[e] == 1) return this[e] = 2, false
  return true;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```