# .splice() function How can I delete only one item ,I have a number of items with the same attribute?

Tags: jquery

```js
window.arrayone = ["1","2","3"];
window.arraytwo = ["1","1","1"];

arrayone.splice(arrayone.indexOf("1",-1));
arraytwo.splice(arraytwo.indexOf("1",-1));

console.log("arrayone -->" + arrayone);
console.log("arraytwo -->" + arraytwo);
```

> How can I delete only one item. I have a number of items with the same
>   attribute. I am trying to delete only one item. I.e array ["1", "1",
>   "1"] Array.splice (array.indexOf (1.1)) Now if I have another set of
>   items. The function does work and subtracts item 1. But when there is
>   a group with similar items it does not work. Can someone tell me?
>
> Answer: Can I close I realized my mistake. DeleteCount should be -1
>   negative. And not as positive as I had in the code.

```
        JAVA SCRIPT

      window.arrayone = ["1","2","3"];
window.arraytwo = ["1","1","1"];

arrayone.splice(arrayone.indexOf("1",1));
arraytwo.splice(arraytwo.indexOf("1",1));

alert("arrayone -->" + arrayone);
alert("arraytwo -->" + arraytwo);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to remove only one value from duplicate array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522191/javascript-how-to-remove-only-one-value-from-duplicate-array-values)

Answer (score 1):

Splice can take two arguments.  The position to start at and the number of elements to remove.  If you only want one element removed then include `splice(startIndex, 1)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control

```js
var test = [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];

console.log(test.toString());

test.splice(test.indexOf(3), 1);

console.log(test.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Can I close I realized my mistake. DeleteCount should be -1 negative. And not as positive as I had in the code.

```
window.arrayone = ["1","2","3"]; window.arraytwo = ["1","1","1"]; arrayone.splice(arrayone.indexOf("1",-1)); arraytwo.splice(arraytwo.indexOf("1",-1)); console.log("arrayone -->" + arrayone); console.log("arraytwo -->" + arraytwo);
```